# egrep -o : different behaviour in Linux and MacOS

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, grep, posix-ere

I have two scripts which I would like to run both in a Linux machine and in a MacOS machine. But a different behaviour of the `egrep` command makes those scripts generate different outputs.

In particular, this is what happens when I use `egrep` on Linux (Ubuntu):

```
$ echo ".test" | egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
.test
$ echo ".test" | egrep -o "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
test
$
```

and this is what happens when I use `egrep` on MacOS

```
$ echo ".test" | egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
.test
$ echo ".test" | egrep -o "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"

$
```

The first behaviour is what I would expect, the second one (empty output) is unexpected. Perhaps this is a bug in the implementation of `egrep` with `-o` option under MacOS?

Or, if the second behaviour is correct as well, do you know a way to obtain the same behaviour for the second case?

I tried to look at the corresponding `man` pages for the two commands, this is extracted from the Linux man page:

```
 -o, --only-matching
        Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each 
        such part on a separate output line.
```

and this is extracted from the man page for MacOS:

```
 -o, --only-matching
         Prints only the matching part of the lines.
```

Although the descriptions seem a bit different, the meaning of the two options seems to be the same, so why is `egrep -o` behaving differently in MacOS? Am I not considering any subtle aspect of this command?

Comment: I removed the comments since everything is [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428855/116858). I will just keep this comment of mine: *In general, it makes no sense to use a regex to extract text that may match an empty string*.

Comment: You can [install the Gnu version](https://gist.github.com/epcim/037f928bb1f806b3e68a) of the utilities (i.e. the one you know from Linux) on the Mac; by default, they get the letter "g" added in front, so that you can distinguish them from the original ones on the Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how the different `grep` implementations deal with empty matches (`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` matches the empty string).

I wrote [a longer text about this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428855/116858) over at Unix&Linux.

In short, should all empty matches be returned?  There are infinitely many such matches.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent source! So the empty output doesn't mean that no matches were found, but that the _empty string_ was a match, right? Perhaps a way to distinguish these two cases is to check the `grep` _exit code_, am I right?

Comment: @Kubuntuer82  That depends on what you want the `grep` to do.  If you really just need to check for a match, then I would use `grep -q` and check the exit status (no `-o` at all).

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 E.g. `if grep -q 'pattern' <<<'string'; then ...; fi`, or the equivalent shell pattern, `if [[ 'string' == pattern ]]` (this uses shell globbing patterns rather than regular expressions though), or `[[ 'string' =~ regex ]]`.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is the first of the two behaviours (that is getting "test" in output), but when I got an empty output I thought there were no matches. I meant that, because of what you said above, when I get an empty line in output I could check the exit code to see what the empty line means (no matches or empty string being a match). But actually if what I want is to get "test" then I just have to make sure I get it, but still checking the exit code is good for debugging I think :-) (I would have got `0` as exit code and perhaps I would have understood that egrep found something).